# Djongo return empty QuerySet when exasing next page

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djongo

This only happens when I made a model to have 2 inheritance from the same model:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    cuvint = models.ForeignKey(KeyWordsMapping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(class)s_cuvint")
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    is_stem = models.BooleanField()
    score_nr = models.ForeignKey(KeyWordsMapping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="%(class)s_score_nr")
    department_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    seniority_id = models.ForeignKey(Seniority, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Everything works fine, but accessing the second page gives me an empty array:

First page:

```
{
    "count": 311,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words?limit=1&offset=1",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "cuvint": "QA",
            "frequency": 4,
            "is_stem": false,
            "score_nr": 100,
            "department_id": "Quality Assurance",
            "seniority_id": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Second page:

```
{
    "count": 311,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words?limit=1&offset=2",
    "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words?limit=1",
    "results": []
}
```

I also looked in the admin panel and the same problem persists.

The view:

```
class WordList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Word.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WordSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The serializer:

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    seniority_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    department_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    score_nr = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cuvint = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ("cuvint", "frequency", "is_stem", "score_nr", "department_id", "seniority_id")

    def get_seniority_id(self, obj):
        if obj.seniority_id:
            return obj.seniority_id.name
        return None

    def get_department_id(self, obj):
        if obj.department_id:
            return obj.department_id.name
        return None

    def get_score_nr(self, obj):
        return obj.score_nr.score_nr

    def get_cuvint(self, obj):
        return obj.cuvint.cuvint
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: The obvious, probably funny question is : and how many elements do you have in your table ? And yes, view and pagination configuration will be helpful too.

Comment: ("count": 311). Went to check Mongo Compass and they are all there.

Comment: Looks good to me. If i take your code and run it, works just fine. Is there anything else we should be aware ?

Comment: I am running Djongo, in order to integrate it with MongoDB as my database.

Comment: @ottomd ah, i haven't noticed that. With that, i cannot help. But I would suggest to use another type of pagination ( PageNumberPagination ) to see if the problem is still present.

Comment: Did you try [PageNumberPagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) ?

Comment: Yes. Same result.